# Regular Expression: 2 digits followed by .. or -- or __ followed by 2 digits

Tags: regex, format

I have a regular expression I need to implement. The rules are

```
 2 digits followed by 
 2 .. or 2 -- or 2 __ followed by 2 digits
it cannot be empty
it cannot have only one pair (i.e. 01)

The string can be up to 1000 characters in length.  
i.e., 
01..02--03  or 
01..01 or 
01--02--03--04--05..06   and so on
```

Comment: @All...thanks for the great answers...I am testing them.  I'll post an acceptance shortly

Comment: A string - at least in most contexts and uses we come accross - can NOT be of infinite length. (And in the few contexts where it can, I don't know of any regex engine that could process an infinite string ;-) .) I guess what you mean is that the string consists of any number of pairs of digits (could it also be empty? could there only be one pair? you should specify that if you want an exact answer), seprated by .. or by -- or by __.

Comment: @Tom...thanks for setting me straight. Yes "infinite" was a poor choice of words. It can be up to 1000 characters. It can not be empty, it can not have only one pair (i.e. 01)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\d{2}(?:(?:[.]{2}|-{2}|_{2})\d{2})+
```

Explanation: Two digits, followed by one or more occurrences of two of the same character consisting of either a period, a hyphen, or an underscore, followed by two more digits.

If you need to anchor this, you can add a `^` at the front and a `$` at the end.

The reason I prefer the use of `{2}` instead of spelling things out (i.e., repeating the same symbol) is that it allows you to increase the number. As the number gets large, counting the number of repeated symbols would get more and more difficult.

Also, depending on your font and screen size, some symbols can get visually merged into one longer symbol making it difficult to ascertain how many of them are in sequence. The undescore character is a prime example of this, consider: `_____` How many underscores is that? Compare and contrast that with this expression: `_{5}`

Comment: this one worked.  am accepting because of the explanation.  thank you

Comment: Good answer, but the expression really needs start `^` and end of string `$` anchors to guarantee the _whole_ string matches. Otherwise this will erroneously match: `"12--34-56789...ABC^#@%$^#$"`.

Comment: I tried the erroneous string and it was not a match.  I think the expression is fine.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
^(?:\d{2}(?:--|\.\.|__))+\d{2}$
```

1. From the beginning of the string do the following:
2. Find 2 digits
3. Follow by `--` or `..` or `__`
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 as many times as possible
5. Make sure it ends with 2 digits

Comment: this one allowed 01 it needs to be at least 01..01. thanks for the answer

Comment: @Marcus...My bad, I neglected to mention that in the original post. thanks again...out of curiosity.  How did you figure it out?   generator or just knowledge?

Comment: @MikeTWebb I made a "guide" for what was needed (the 5 steps mentioned in the answer). Then I translated each part separately and at last put it all together. When it all was in place I added the `?:` in each group since it's not necessary to capture the contents in the groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d\d((?:\.\.|--|__)\d\d)+$
```

Here is your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Regexpal.com:

`(\d{2}(\.{2}|-{2}|_{2}))+\d{2}`

This will not allow numbers like 01.-02